# How can I create links to specific chapters in the text?

Tags: hyperref

Im using `LaTeX` without any addons or special styles (regular `article` class).

I would like to create links to specific sections in the text. When I write "... as described in section 1.1.2" I would like to have the 1.1.2 clickable, so that the reader doesn't have to scroll to it. I believe this is possible through `hyperref`, but I haven't found a good tutorial for this yet.

This is my code for `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = darkgray,
urlcolor = blue,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = blue] {hyperref}
```

Comment: well simply use `\label`/`\ref` . It should work out of the box.

Comment: Specifically, you add `\label{name}` immediately after `\section{...}` using a unique name.  Then you can place `\ref{name}` anywhere in the document and get the section number and a hyperlink (if loaded).